# Setting left view to the TextField with its bottom

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I want to set the Leftview to the TextField. But I want to align it to the bottom of the Textfield. So that the leftview frame looks align to the TextField actual text. But I am not getting any luck.

here is how I am trying with it.

```
let btnSelectCountry = UIButton()
btnSelectCountry.setTitle(title, for: UIControlState.normal)

btnSelectCountry.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, -10, 0)

btnSelectCountry.backgroundColor = CommonUtils.hexStringToUIColor(hex: "#000000")
btnSelectCountry.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: CGFloat(0), width: CGFloat(70), height: CGFloat(25))
btnSelectCountry.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.selectCountryCallingCode), for: .touchUpInside)
etPhoneNum.leftView = btnSelectCountry
etPhoneNum.leftViewMode = .always
etPhoneNum.leftViewRect(forBounds: CGRect(x: 0, y: CGFloat(-100), width: CGFloat(70), height: CGFloat(25)))
```

But it is showing vertically aligned in the TextField. How can I move LeftView to bottom inside the TextField??

Answer (score 0):

```
   func setTextLeftView(){

        txtField.leftView = UIImageView.init(image: image)
        txtField.leftView?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 5, width: 20 , height:20)
        txtField.leftViewMode = .always

    }
```

try this and if it does't work for you then let me know if would like to solve your problem :)

Comment: @Androidteem what u want to achieve ? let me kn so i will try to give u solution like that

Comment: or upload pic of ur psd or design how do u want to achive

Comment: I dont have psd , its like I want to set the left view. I am able to set the left view and it looks fine. its centrally vertical of the height of TextField . I just want to make it stick/align to the bottom of the TextField